# windows defender 32bit does not stop working

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I have windows 10 pro 64bit on my HP pavilion15 laptop. recently some minutes after system boots up, `windows defender user interface 32bit` starts working and takes more than 30% of CPU and does not stop. when I open file location it is at `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe`. I can kill the task but mainly I want to know why does this happen and how to fix this? I have not installed any Adobe product last month this issue occurs last 2 days.

Comment: `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe` This is very suspect... Did you check that very file with an anti-virus?

Comment: yes, I have ESET smart security and it did not detect any thing

Comment: You Windows defender EXE would NOT end up in that folder, it should be in `C:\Program Files\Windows Defender` so you have a problem.  Send that file through virustotal.com to check it against multiple AV's, and run a malware detector like Malwarebytes.  As @xenoid suggests, that "Windows defender" being located in that folder definitely seems like a sign that you're infected. Personally I'd say format your drives, and start over from scratch.

Comment: ***Adobe*** \ Windows Defender ??? That is *definitely* not right. Upload the file to https://virustotal.com/ and scan it there. Share a link to the results here.